# Как отсортировать массив содержащий массивы и объекты WordPress по двум параметрам?

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [format] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                //прочее                    
            )
        [variants] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [variant] => WP_Term Object
                            (                                    
                                [name] => 'Иван'
                                //прочее
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [format] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                //прочее                    
            )
        [variants] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [variant] => WP_Term Object
                            (                                    
                                [name] => 'Алексей'
                                //прочее
                            )
                    )
            )
      )
)
```

Есть такой сложный массив, как отсортировать его по значениям `name` и потом по значениям `id` ?

Comment: по сути id и name нужно в результирующем массиве?
    foreach($your_array as $v){$result_array[$v['format']['id']] = $v['variants'][0][variant]['name'];}

Comment: @sterx нужно, после сортировки я должен вывести все данные в виде таблицы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($your_array as $k=>$v){
    $key = $v['variants'][0][variant]['name'] . $v['format']['id'];
    $result_array[$key]= $v;
}
ksort($result_array);unset($your_array);$k=0;
foreach($result_array as $v){$your_array[$k] = $v;$k++;}
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, возможно я неправильно выразился. Мне нужны не только эти поля. Ваше решение не сортирует изначальный массив, а создает новый, извлекая только эти два поля. В массиве на самом деле намного больше разных данных, которые я скрыл, чтобы облегчить понимание задачи. Все они важны.

Comment: поправил свой ответ, структура сохранена.
пс: обычно сортируют выборку из БД, так проще и быстрее

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, очень хорошее решение и все работает =) Единственное, что необходимо было поправить, к WP объекту надо обращаться через `->`. P.S. Этот массив формируется в cookies =)